# How can I use the @BeforeEach method for testing in Java?

Tags: java, testing, installation, junit

I am learning Test Driven Development with JUnit5. In my reader this is written: " Annotations are added above a method to specify its behavior. A common scenario we find ourselves in is that
we have to create a new object for each test. Instead of doing this in each test method, we can create a new method called setUp() for example, and add the @beforeEach annotation. This will make sure that this method is executed before each test method." But I don't know how can I use an object from a method in another method. Any help, please? This is my code:

```
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp(){
        IntSet set = new IntSet(4);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIntSet(){
        assertEquals(set.getCapacity(), 4); //error here: Cannot resolve symbol 'set'
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have all your tests in a class, right? Make it a property/instance variable:

```java
class SomeTests {
    IntSet set;

    @BeforeEach 
    public void setUp() { 
        set = new IntSet(4); 
    } 

    @Test 
    public void testIntSet() { 
        assertEquals(set.getCapacity(), 4); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare `IntSet set` as a field in your test class. Then, you can initialize the field in the @BeforeEach method.

```
class MyTest{
private IntSet set;

@BeforeEach
    public void setUp(){
        set = new IntSet(4);
    }

    @Test
    public void testIntSet(){
        assertEquals(set.getCapacity(), 4); //error here: Cannot resolve symbol 'set'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your variable outside of the  `setUp()` method. This way it is accessible for any method.

```
private IntSet set;

@BeforeEach
public void setUp(){
    set = new IntSet(4);
}

@Test
public void testIntSet(){
    assertEquals(set.getCapacity(), 4); //error here: Cannot resolve symbol 'set'
    }
```